# Какими средствами проще организовать клиент-серверное приложение с одним клиентом и множеством серверов?

Tags: c#, клиент-сервер

Какими средствами проще организовать следующее:
Несколько однотипных приложений с определённой периодичностью посылает основному сгенерированные числа, после чего то обрабатывает эти числа.

Всё это запускается на одном ПК.

UPD: Предполагается, что это будут отдельные приложения. Главное запускается в одном экземпляре и (небольшое исправление) запрашивает у остальных значение некоторой переменной.

UPD2: Это должны быть отдельные процессы, обменивающиеся данными.

Comment: GET запрос от клиента к серверу на http://site.com/getnumber.php?clientid=1 и дальше делайте с ответом что хотите. В чем проблема - не ясно.

Comment: С точки зрения классической клиент-серверной архитектуры, вопрос сформулирован некорректно. *Сервер* это тот, кто обслуживает, а клиента, кто запрашивает обслуживание и получает результат. А когда куча серверов (?) посылают клиенту (?!) запросы, то не понятно кто из них кто.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как предложил Vesper, если речь идет об одной машине, то лучшим решением будет многопоточная архитектура.

Данные из дочерних потоков можно синхронизировать с родительским потоком через message loop (разумеется в том случае, если у программы есть окно. Тогда message loop организуется автоматически средствами ОС).

Если окна нет, то тогда систему обмена сообщениями надо будет писать самому. Но окно, я полагаю, все же есть.

Из дочерних потоков можно передавать в главный указатели на сложные типы с помощью `PostMessage` или `SendMessage` (функции Windows API). А главный поток "отлавливает" эти сообщения и визуализирует результаты.

**UPDATE**
*По словам автора вопроса, речь идет об учебной задаче с необходимостью запуска нескольких оконный приложений*.

В этом случае общением между оконными приложениями можно делать через тот же глобальный message loop, организованный операционноной системой, только в вышеуказанные функции передавать дескрипторы HWND: WindowHandle для того, чтобы сообщение доставлялось "правильному" окну. При запуске основным приложением всех последующих окон надо запоминать HWND всех создаваемых окон для того, чтобы с ними потом общаться. Однако обмен результатами может быть затруднен, потому что у каждого окна своя собственная область рабочей памяти и попытки передать указатели на области других окон будут приводить к AV.

В [PostMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944(v=vs.85).aspx) можно передавать UINT-значения через wParam и lParam.

**UPDATE2**
Ответ будет неполным, без вот этих ссылок (русский яз.):

- [IPC: основы межпроцессного взаимодействия](http://rsdn.ru/article/baseserv/ipc.xml)
- [Википедия: межпроцессное взаимодействие](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Тут много чего можно изучить и понять, поэтому в целом вопрос годный. А по техникам реализации IPC решение принимать автору.

Comment: Предполагается, что это будут отдельные приложения. Главное запускается в одном экземпляре и (небольшое исправление) запрашивает у остальных значение некоторой переменной.

Comment: @InfernumDeus, так это и есть классическая многопоточная задача. Надеюсь, меня здесь никто не заругает, если я строго в обсуждаемом контектсе назову *отдельные приложения* по сути *дочерними потоками*.

Comment: Понятно, буду разбираться, спасибо.

Comment: @InfernumDeus иными словами, для чего запускать много экземпляров окон, потом организовывать между ними IPC, когда разработчики ОС позаботились о нас и предложили многопоточную архитектуру?

Comment: Но мне нужно именно несколько экземпляров окон. Сервер запрашивает значение переменной из каждого дочернего приложения. А каждое дочернее, насколько понимаю, после запуска сообщает серверу о том, что оно запустилось, и начинает выполнять свои функции.

Comment: Т.е., должны быть отдельные процессы, обменивающиеся данными.

Comment: @InfernumDeus, очень похоже на учебную задачу. Потому что я слабо себе представляю UI (на одной машине!) с кучей окон по всему десктопу, которые что-то делают и сообщают об изменениях главному окну. Выглядит весело, но неправдоподобно)))

Comment: Да, учебная задача.

Comment: @InfernumDeus, я сейчас дополню ответ схожими методиками, которые, надеюсь, решат задачу.

Comment: А ещё требуется использовать для связи WinAPI. Но, как понимаю, он в любом случае будет так или иначе использован.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Теперь знаю, в каком направлении копать.

Comment: Возник побочный вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/442146/

Comment: Никак не пойму, как написать в принимающем приложении метод для обработки полученных сообщений, отправленных методом SendMessage. Подскажите, что следует использовать?

Comment: Нашел только примеры на C++.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083954/send-message-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 5):

Если на одном ПК, то многопоточная архитектура и сокеты для внутрипроцессного общения.

PS: По идее, тот, кто принимает запросы, это сервер, то есть всё-таки здесь один сервер и много клиентов. Клиенты посылают числа, сервер обрабатывает.

Comment: Я бы заменил сокеты на организацию цикла сообщений (message pump). А в остальном я +1 твой ответ на этот не совсем корректный вопрос.

Comment: Понятно, благодарю.

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown Вариант named pipes тоже вариант. (В принципе, любая структура межпроцессного общения с организацией FIFO подойдет под задачу)

Comment: @Vesper, да, я согласен. Тем более что условия задачи потихоньку начинают корректироваться ;)

Answer (score 2):

- WCF-сервис в том приложении, которое должно обрабатывать запросы
- WCF-клиенты в тех приложениях, которые должны запросы отправлять.

В качестве основы можно взять [Как размещать и запускать базовую службу Windows Communication Foundation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms730935(v=vs.110).aspx). Там как раз пример с калькулятором.

Любой другой туториал по WCF тоже подойдет.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы использовал удалённые методы из арсенала C# (http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/6897bc/net-remoting-calling-remote-method-using-delegates/), если приложения все на c#

Из других вариантов не предложенных тут:

- Через базу
- Через файлы

Comment: Так на одном компе-то все ;-)

Comment: А какая разница?

Comment: Ремоутинг? в 2015 году? :)

Comment: Ну мы же до сих пор пользуемся вентиляторами например? :-) Или деньгами. :-) Технология должна быть удобной для использования, с минимум писанины кода.