# Как получить идентификаторы отдельных процессов в локальном клиент-серверном приложении?

Tags: c#, клиент-сервер

Имеется оконное серверное приложение и консольное клиентское. Сервер запускается в одном экземпляре, а клиент в нескольких. Нужно, чтобы они обменивались сообщениями через message loop.

Подсказали, что для их взаимодействия следует получить какой-то, уникальный для каждого, идентификатор:

> В этом случае общением между оконными приложениями можно делать через
>   тот же глобальный message loop, организованный операционной
>   системой, только в вышеуказанные функции передавать дескрипторы HWND:
>   WindowHandle для того, чтобы сообщение доставлялось "правильному"
>   окну.

По логике моего приложения, клиент должен иметь доступ к серверу, а сервер к каждому клиенту.

Каким образом это можно реализовать?

Comment: Не очень удобно сейчас писать с телефона, но попробую дать ответ.

Comment: Можете написать в любое время до завтра.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если процессы уже запущены и известны заголовки их окон (Window caption) то можно использовать функцию WinAPI `FindWindow` (или `FindWindowEx`). Это простейший способ. Например вот так:

```
HWND Handle = FindWindow(NULL, "Your App - Window Caption");
```

Если мы сами стартуем процессы, то сразу после старта мы можем получать их PID'ы и через эти идентификаторы получать HWND.

Посмотрите функции `EnumWindows`, call-back функцию `EnumWindowsProc` и `GetModuleFileName`. Функций много, техник программирования тоже много. И самое главное, эти API-функции сейчас хорошо документированы. Времена Windows NT давно миновали...

**UPDATE**

> *А если запущенно несколько одинаковых процессов, как каждый из них
>   может определить свой собственный HWND?*

```
Window window = Window.GetWindow(this);
var wHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(window);
IntPtr hWnd = wHandle.Handle;
```

Comment: `typedef HANDLE HWND;` объявлена в `WinDef.h`

Comment: Живой пример: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14519/Using-Windows-APIs-from-C-again

Comment: Разобрался немного иначе: `int Handle = FindWindow(null, "Заголовок окна");`

Comment: А если запущенно несколько одинаковых процессов, как каждый из них может определить свой собственный HWND?

Comment: дополнил ответ.